# Is it possible for the database to block parallel table accesses in Scala threads?

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, scala

In my **Scala** application, I make several threads. In each thread, I write different data from the array to the same PostgreSQL table. I noticed that some threads did not write data to the PostgreSQL table. However, there are no errors in the application logs. Is it possible for the database to block parallel table accesses? What can be the cause of this behavior?

**MainApp.scala:**

```
val postgreSQL = new PostgreSQL(configurations)

val semaphore = new Semaphore(5)

for (item <- array) {
    semaphore.acquire()

    val thread = new Thread(new CustomThread(postgreSQL, semaphore, item))

    thread.start()
}
```

**CustomThread.scala:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore
import java.util.UUID.randomUUID
import utils.PostgreSQL

class CustomThread(postgreSQL: PostgreSQL, semaphore: Semaphore, item: Item) extends Runnable {
    override def run(): Unit = {
        try {
            // Create the unique filename.
            val filename: String = randomUUID().toString

            // Write to the database the filename of the item.
            postgreSQL.changeItemFilename(filename, item.id)

            // Change the status type of the item.
            postgreSQL.changeItemStatusType(3, request.id)
        } catch {
            case e: Throwable =>
                e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            semaphore.release()
        }
    }
}
```

**PostgreSQL.scala:**

```
package utils

import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager, PreparedStatement, ResultSet}
import java.util.Properties

class PostgreSQL(configurations: Map[String, String]) {
  val host: String = postgreSQLConfigurations("postgresql.host")
  val port: String = postgreSQLConfigurations("postgresql.port")
  val user: String = postgreSQLConfigurations("postgresql.user")
  val password: String = postgreSQLConfigurations("postgresql.password")
  val db: String = postgreSQLConfigurations("postgresql.db")
  val url: String = "jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + db
  val driver: String = "org.postgresql.Driver"

  val properties = new Properties()

  val connection: Connection = getConnection

  var statement: PreparedStatement = _

  def getConnection: Connection = {
    properties.setProperty("user", user)
    properties.setProperty("password", password)

    var connection: Connection = null

    try {
      Class.forName(driver)
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties)
    } catch {
      case e:Exception =>
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    connection
  }

  def changeItemFilename(filename: String, id: Int): Unit = {
    try {
      statement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE REPORTS SET FILE_NAME = ? WHERE ID = ?;", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)
      statement.setString(1, filename)
      statement.setInt(2, id)
      statement.execute()
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: PostgreSQL will use locks to stall operations that are incompatible with others, like different transactions trying to modify the same table row. One transaction is blocked until the other one is done. Not sure if that's what you are experiencing.

Comment: As Laurenz wrote: if two transactions are trying to modify the same row, the second one will wait until the first finishes. The second one might then overwrite values set by the first. You could change all transactions to use the `serializable` isolation level then you would at least get an error if such a situation occurs

Comment: Also, if the block takes long, it may be that you forget to end the transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Just for your interest, by default, JDBC is *synchronous*. It means that it blocks your thread until the operation is done on a specific connection. This means if you try to do multiple things on a single connection at the same time, actions will be done sequentially instead.

More on that:
https://dzone.com/articles/myth-asynchronous-jdbc

That's the first and the most probable reason. The second possible reason, database blocks modifying actions on table cells which are being updated by another transaction, how exactly - depends on *isolation level*.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/isolation-levels-in-sql-server

That's the second probable reason.

The last, but not least, it is not necessary to use *bare threads* in Scala. For concurrent/asynchronous programming many of libraries like [cats-effects](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/), [monix](https://monix.io/), [zio](https://github.com/zio/zio), was developed, and there are special libraries for database access using these libraries like [slick](http://scala-slick.org/) or [doobie](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie).
It's better to use them than bare threads due to numerous reasons.

Comment: Note that isolation levels in Postgres differ from SQL Server (most notably: `serializable` is way more efficient in Postgres than it is in SQL Server)